# ASP.NET free (open source) ecommerce site that allows multisite branding?

Tags: .net, portal, branding, affiliate

I'm looking for a free/open source ecommerce product. Specifically what I need is multisite support that allows each site to be branded for the vendor. Basically, I have a brick and mortar business and I'd like to provide a service that allows people to have their own website that accesses my inventory. Sort of like CafePress.com but not exactly.

I've looked at mojoPortal (doesn't have a fully functional ecommerce), nopCommerce, dashCommerce, and DNN. I didn't find a reference to multisite in the features.  I suspect that DNN might be able to do this based on the size of the support.

Does anyone have any experience with the above mentioned with regard to multisite ecommerce?

Comment: Turns out that many of the products support multisite / portals but I haven't found any that all branding for a client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While many products supported muiltsite/portals I didn't find anything that allowed a transparent branding of a portal.

My solution is to take NB_Store http://www.codeplex.com/NBStore, an open source ecommerce module for DNN, and modify the code do what I want.

Comment: I've made a bit of progress on this topic.  I'm currently looking at using Wordpress 3 (Multisite), buddypress, and a commerce plugin.  Looks like it's possible to do what I want with this but...

Answer (score 1):

You could do it a little simpler for yourself, and get something in place faster.

Instead of offering your vendors an ecommerce site, offer them a set of web services that they can use to check your inventory, as well as making reservations and orders.

This would be used by the vendors that are able to have their own site or would like to integrate their backend systems.

Later you can use the same web services for your ecommerce site.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The point is to provide a branded portal to the client. An SOA layer would not meet this goal.  These are people that don't even have a web site let alone a back end system.  An SOA layer may make sense in the future though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm familiar with Nopcommerce and am pretty confident you could do this either by setting up multiple different sites or one site with multiple themes where the correct theme (including brand) is used depending on the domain/subdomain...and removing the Nopcommerce text only costs $50 making it a pretty cost effective solution...

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't see anything on their website for that.  Can you provide a specific reference?

Comment: Sorry, I meant a reference to the multiple themes.